# ClassNotFoundException for Zookeeper while building Storm

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I'm new to java and Storm so please forgive any obvious mistakes.
I'm trying to run storm with a flume connector
but It crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at backtype.storm.cluster$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(cluster.clj:1)
    at backtype.storm.cluster__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.cluster__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5381)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at backtype.storm.testing$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(testing.clj:1)
    at backtype.storm.testing__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.testing__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5227)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5264)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:603)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5302)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:605)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5392)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:1)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2056)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:400)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke(core.clj:5415)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5414)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.storm.WordCountTopology.main(WordCountTopology.java:97)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper$loading__4784__auto__.invoke(zookeeper.clj:1)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at backtype.storm.zookeeper__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 96 more
```

My pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-storm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>my-storm</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <flume.version>1.3.0-cdh4.2.1</flume.version>
        <hadoop.version>2.0.0-cdh4.2.1</hadoop.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>cdh-maven-repo</id>
            <name>CDH Maven Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
            <artifactId>flume-ng-embedded-agent</artifactId>
            <version>${flume.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
            <artifactId>flume-ng-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flume.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
            <artifactId>flume-ng-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${flume.version}</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
                <artifactId>flume-ng-node</artifactId>
                <version>${flume.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
                <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
                <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.5</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
       <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



 $uname -a :Linux 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 17 10:27:22 CEST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    $locate zookeeper
       .m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5-cdh4.2.1/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.2.1.pom
```

Can you please explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the key is here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory
```

This seems caused by using the version `3.4.5` of `zookeeper`. Have you tried a downgrade to, maybe version `3.3.6`?

The branch-3.3 contains that Inner Class [NIOServerCnxn$Factory](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/branch-3.3/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/NIOServerCnxn.java#L77) but the branch-3.4 has the [NIOServerCnxnFactory](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/branch-3.4/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/server/NIOServerCnxnFactory.java#L38) instead

Comment: this is the correct solution. explicitly include zookeeper 3.3.6 and the missing class becomes resolvable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that final jar is missing zookeeper. Try adding this:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flume</groupId>
        <artifactId>flume-ng-core</artifactId>
        <version>${flume.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
  <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml.

If it doesn't help issue :

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and send me output.

Comment: I'm getting this http://pastebin.com/WjeM3k02
new pom: http://pastebin.com/GdX6LVdT

Comment: Your project dies in test phase, so it seems that you have to add <scope>test</scope> for zookeeper dependency.

Comment: I did, now I'm getting this http://pastebin.com/FezMZ6HJ
As you can see, it dies in the same line for a different reason Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.data.Stat

Comment: Let's get rid of slf4j warning first. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @user987339 you can't use slf4j > 1.5.8 with Storm 0.8.2. You'll get troubles when you will deploy on cluster.

Comment: @zenebi Thanks. I didn't know that. I'll change the answer.

Comment: The output: http://pastebin.com/hz0iu4W5
and the new pom http://pastebin.com/LBcPSFqC

Comment: Send mvn dependency:tree output.

Comment: It seems that flume-ng-core is using slf4j 1.6.1, so we'll exclude it. I've updated answer. Try it and pastebin output of mvn test and mvn dependency:tree

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/Wz7xFbfE
for some reason the depndency for the 1.6 slf4j is still there

Comment: Add to all your dependency sections <scope>test</scope>. Try it and pastebin output of mvn test and mvn dependency:tree

Comment: But there is no exception as I've noticed?

Comment: the test does not raise exceptions since there are no tests to run, if I try to run the project with  mvn test exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=com.storm.WordCountTopology I get the exception

Comment: We moved all the dependencies to test. Try with: mvn test-compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=test -exec.mainClass=com.storm.WordCountTopology

Comment: try also with -Dexec.classpathScope="test"

Comment: didn't work, failed with same error, maybe something is wrong with my environment, I'll try diving into it a bit more and I'll post any results

Comment: "Solved" it (well not really because maven still refuses to run but I'm out of time so...) Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

The below POM works for me -

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
        <artifactId>esper</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, the problem i noticed in my case is:
I am using storm-9.0.1 with Zookeeper 3.4.5.

By change my zookeeper to 3.3.6 or by changing the storm to 9.0.2,My problem have solved.

So Storm-9.0.1 is compatibility with Zookeeper 3.3.6 and Storm 9.0.2 is compatibility with Zookeeper 3.4.5

Answer (score -1):

After some days of banging my head I decided to change the aproach, aparently Eclipse could run the project as it was without any issue.

Creating an uberjar from eclipse and puting all the referenced jars in the project's lib folder and then running the uberjar in the server using java -jar solved the issue.

Not a good solution and I never understood why maven couldn't run the project but it works.