# Class org/apache/zookeeper/server/NIOServerCnxn$Factory not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We've recently added Kafka usage into our J2EE application, however we get the following error during glassfish start (initialization):

```
Class [ Lorg/apache/zookeeper/server/NIOServerCnxn$Factory; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkServer ]]]
```

Looking at a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958635/classnotfoundexception-for-zookeeper-while-building-storm) it recommends to downgrade the zookeeper version, however my project is not controlling the zookeeper's version directly (as far as I know), as it depends on org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.1, which internally depends on zookeeper 3.4.6.

What is causing this error and also - what is the implication of the error, as basically all seems to work.

Comment: I have found the reason for this: Using kafka_2.10:0.8.2.1 requires (internally by the JAR, not by me) zookeeper:3.4.6 & zkclient:0.3, however that causes a mismatch: While zookeeper:3.3.x had a class NIOServerCnxn$Factory (Factory as inner class), in 3.4.x it became an independent class (NIOServerCnxnFactory), however ZkServer class of zkclient:0.3 is still using (importing) NIOServerCnxn.Factory and only in 0.5 changes to use NIOServerCnxnFactory. 
This looks like an issue of kafka_2.10 - any suggestions or comments?

Comment: The finalization is in the answer bellow. Basically it is either not solved in this kafka version, but you can workaround it by upgrading to zkclient 0.5 or higher, just make sure nothing else is broken by this change.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious from the error that you are not including the class from zookeeper that Kafka requires. After reading your edit I think you might try updating the version of zkclient to 0.5 manually in your projects pom.xml

Comment: I'll explain: I meant the kafka project has a dependency on the zookeeper and that it requires it. As for not including, basically the mechanism works as we do write successfully to kafka and so.

Comment: Are you using Maven or something else to manage your transitive dependencies?

Comment: Yes, we're using Maven

Comment: So to finalize the discussion: what are the implications of it? I guess the ZooKeeper is important, however de-facto all seems to work plus I guess many users are encountering this (as it was not reported so far), so how come?