# Failed to write pid zookeeper installing zookeeper

Tags: java, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I was following previous posts but still not able to resolve the issue. I am trying to install zookeeper and start it to run summing-bird which is run to provide bolts/spouts to storm for online and batch. I installed zookeeper version 3.4.6 first and was getting class not found exception. After looking at the post

[ClassNotFoundException for Zookeeper while building Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958635/classnotfoundexception-for-zookeeper-while-building-storm)

I downgraded the version to 3.3.6 and now I am not even able to start the zookeeper server. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
root@cp-1:/users/username/zookeeper-3.3.6/bin# ./zkServer.sh start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /users/username/zookeeper-3.3.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... ./zkServer.sh: 93: [: /tmp/zookeeper/: unexpected  operator
./zkServer.sh: 103: ./zkServer.sh: cannot create /tmp/zookeeper/
The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir/zookeeper_server.pid: Directory   nonexistent
FAILED TO WRITE PID
```

This is how my zoo.cfg file looks like

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just
# example sakes.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper/
dataLogDir=/tmp/logs/zookeeper/

# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1

server.1=10.11.10.3:2888:3888
server.2=10.11.10.4:2888:3888
```

This is how access looks like

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 username oppts-PG0    4096 Nov 25 14:35 zookeeper
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root         4096 Nov 25 14:46 logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 25 14:46 logs/zookeeper
```

Comment: The error indicates that there is an error during script execution. Are you running in a bash shell? The script is not able to get "dataDir" from you configuration file, thus the internal script var ZOOPIDFILE is empty and the script crashed... Are you pointing to the correct zoo.cfg file, ie, in `/users/username/zookeeper-3.3.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg` ?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax : Yes, I am pointing it to the right direction. I did a hack to resolve this issue by download latest version of zookeeper and then copying zkServer.sh file to the older version and since then I am not facing this problem. It's weird but it worked for me.

Comment: i didn't get how can you solved it, can you please illustrate more i'm facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the contents of `zoo.cfg`, you’d not better to set the `dataDir` to `/tmp/zookeeper`.

```
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just
# example sakes.
```

You can try to set dataDir to other directory that you created. And then restart `zkServer.sh`.